# how to get product2

Tags: trigger

here i am trying to fetch name from opportunitylineitem but its fetching null, don't know how to solve this problem. 
Can anyone please help me out.

```
>  for(OpportunityLineItem o : oli)
>            {  
>             OrderItem op = new OrderItem(); 
>         op.Order_Name__c = o.Product2.Name;
>          orderIt.add(op);
>             
>            }
```

Comment: Is it vf or a trigger ?

Comment: Post the query that you're using to build 'oli' - you need to include there Product fields in it

Comment: actually oli is a list that i m passing using trigger, List<OpportunityLineItem> oli, i am not using any query.

Answer (score 0):

As you are calling this method from trigger so you can't direct access parent field from the 'Trigger.New' what you can do here is first store product ID in set and query of Product object and get Name of product and store it in the map. Now iterate over the list and using the Product Id get Product name from Map and ust it in your code.